# jQuery: AJAX request fires multiple times until response is successfully using $.Deferreds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

### Problem!

While trying to perform a set of AJAX request, most of the time at least one of the request is always getting a pending response, this is resulting in a loop of requests until it gets a succesful response. Please note that I using `jQuery.when`, this way I can ensure that both requests have been executed.

The mentioned behaviour is resulting on:

- Multiple requests to the same source
- `jQuery.always` is executes as many times as requests performed
- The interface is crashing due to multiple updates on it's DOM.

### Example

```
var request = [];

request.push(getProductPrice().done(
  function(price) {
    updateProductPrice(price);
  }
);

request.push(getProductInfo().done(
  function(information) {
    updateProductInformation(information);
  }
);

jQuery.when.apply(undefined, request).always(function() {
  doSomeStuff1();
  doSomeStuff2();

  ...
  ...
  ...

  doSomeStuffN();
});


function updateProductPrice(obj) {
  return jQuery.get(...);
}

function updateProductInformation(obj) {
  return jQuery.get(...);
}
```

### Questions?

- Is there any reason on why I am getting a pending response?
- Is this problem realted to `jQuery.when` trying to release the AJAX request in order to fire-up the callbacks?

### Facts

- If I do the request to the mentioned sources via synchronous, I will never get a pending response. I am just trying to avoid the use of `async: false`.

### Update #1

By pending status I meant the response given by the web browser to my request, which is nothing but the ajax call waiting for it's response. The main problem resides on how those AJAX request are being treated, I am noticing that the functions `updateProdcutPrice()` and `updateProductInformation()` are being called N times until the response from the server is succesful, this is resulting that the functions declared on the `.always()`'s callback for the requestes performed on `updateProdcutPrice()` and `updateProductInformation()` are also being called that many times.

Comment: What do you mean by "get a pending response" and how is it observed?

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena: Wouldn't the response be delayed due to it's bit amount of data?, I do get the response, but I see that the functions that handles the AJAX requests are called many times.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Could you please look above to my update. **Update #1**